# Blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

My client is been blocked by my backend API when I use my web app and do many calls from the browser (I'm not having this issue when I try it on postman), sometimes in one method sometimes in other, GET or POST.

I'm using nodejs and express in the backend, this is my **index.js:**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var express = require('express');

var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true}));
```

And in the frontend I'm using react and I do the API calls with Axios:

I define the baseURL in **App.js**:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'API_URL/api';
```

And the get/post calls in the redux/actions:

```
export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
    axios.post('/login', userData)
    .then((res) => {
        setAuthorizationHeader(res.data.token);
        dispatch(getUserData());
        dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS});
        history.push('/');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data
        });
    });
};


export const getProfileData = (userHandle) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_PROFILE });
    axios.get(`/user/${userHandle}`)
    .then((res) => {
        dispatch({
            type: SET_PROFILE,
            payload: res.data
        });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
...
```

The error I'm having:
[image]

I know this is a very repeated issue, but I've read many post and didn't find a solution...

Comment: Try adding `app.options('*', cors())` to your `index.js`. See the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: I've tried but nothing happens, I think that my problem is coming from the frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was caused by several triggers I have deployed to firebase. They were creating lot of calls to Firebase Functions and exceeding the quota, so the solution was to change the plan.